# Retrieve NSURL Data when loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a the following retrieveData method in my SendData class. I call this class from my MovieViewController. The method checks if the data fetched from the server is correct, if it is, it returns TRUE. If it is not, it returns FALSE. It works just fine except the method returns to my MovieViewController before the data has time to "download". Hence the method always returns false because it is always null because control is returned to the original view controller.

How do I return (AKA exit with the method with the returned value) only when the data has finished loading and not before?

Thanks!

**SendData.m**

```
-(BOOL)retrieveData:(NSString *) postID:(NSString *) message:(NSString *)token
{

    __block BOOL value=FALSE;
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                                   @"message" : message,
                                                   @"access_token": token
                                                   };

    postID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/comments?message=%@&access_token=%@",postID,message,token];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postID]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        //THIS NEEDS TO BE EXECUTED BEFORE THE METHOD IS RETURNED
        BOOL valid;
        NSString* myString;
        myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"MY string is %@", myString);

        if (myString != NULL || [myString length] != 0)
        {
            valid = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = FALSE;
        }
        value=valid;
    }];
    return value;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the delegate pattern. You have to add the following property to `SendData`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
```

and method:

```
- (void)dataDownloaded:(NSNumber *)result
```

to `MovieViewController`.

Then in `MovieViewController` you have to set (I assume here that sendData is an object of class SendData):

```
sendData.delegate = self;
```

Then you have to change the definition to:

```
-(void)retrieveData:(NSString *) postID:(NSString *) message:(NSString *)token
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                                   @"message" : message,
                                                   @"access_token": token
                                                   };

    postID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/comments?message=%@&access_token=%@",postID,message,token];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postID]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        //THIS NEEDS TO BE EXECUTED BEFORE THE METHOD IS RETURNED
        BOOL valid;
        NSString* myString;
        myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"MY string is %@", myString);

        if (myString != NULL || [myString length] != 0)
        {
            valid = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = FALSE;
        }

        [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataDownloaded:) withObject:@(valid) waitUntilDone:NO];
    }];
}
```

You could also check if `self.delegate` responds to `dataDownloaded:` with:

```
[self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dataDownloaded:)]
```

Alternatively, instead of the delegate pattern, you could use blocks or `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz! Just wondering, I have read that performing on the main thread is not a good idea. Do you agree?

Comment: Of course. Doing this on the background thread requires you to rethink your architecture. With my changes you'll know if the request succeeded only when `dataDownloaded:` is called. But it'd certainly be better from the user experience point of view.

Comment: I see, thank you. One last question, I am fairly new to iOS dev (I am a student), is calling performSelectorInBackground the way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: It could be, but it depends on your code. Changes in UI aren't thread-safe, so if you're going to change something in your interface in `dataDownloaded:` then it's best to just use `performSelectorOnMainThread:`. You might want to read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via NSURLConnection, but **do not run this on the main thread** or you have a very real chance of freezing your application for multiple minutes while waiting for the request to complete:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postID]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request addValue:message forHTTPHeaderField:@"message"];
[request addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"access_token"];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks how would I run this in the background?